# Selenium WebDriver getCssValue() is not returning anything for background-repeat-x

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to verify that a background image is present and that the property is set to repeat for x.

Getting the image with

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body").getCssValue("background-image");
```

returns something I can parse so I'm all good there.

However, when I try to get the repeat-x property, I get no output:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body").getCssValue("background-repeat-x");
```

The css, as seen in element viewer in Chrome, looks like this:

```
background: #213A6A url('/images/background.png') repeat-x top;
background-image: url(http://mysite/images/background.png);
background-position-x: 50%;
background-position-y: 0%;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: repeat;
background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: rgb(33, 58, 106);
```

Any help, gratefully received. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you test the value of the 'background-repeat' property is 'repeat no-repeat' ?

Comment: Ahah! Yes you can. Fantastic, I can just parse that result. Brilliant!