# How to validate an image in the class properties in selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to validate an image which is in the class property here is the code snippet..

```
<img class="sprite edit-adv-icon" alt="Master" src="http://images/spacer.png">

and class property like below :

.edit-adv-icon {
    background-position: -689px -2px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 35px;`enter code here`
}
icon-s...-v1.css (line 41)
.sprite {
    background: url("../images/icon-sprite-v1.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Try the `getCssValue()` method on the WebElement. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337043/selenium-webdriver-getcssvalue-not-returning-anything-for-background-repeat-x) as an example.

Comment: yes but "icon-sprite-v1.png" this file is set of the images and i want to validate the particular image from it.......

Comment: So the real question is that you want selenium to validate which portion of your sprite is actually visible and not whether the image (sprite) is visible. Don't believe you can do that with selenium since you actually want to do a comparison based on the image and not the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WebDriver#getCssValue` method as mentioned in the comment and than assert the returned value. So for instance if you want to check `display` property

```
String displayValue = driver.findElement(By.className("sprite edit-adv-icon"))
   .getCssValue("display");
Assert.assertEquals("inline-block", displayValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways I have been able to achieve this is by below mentioned logic

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.id("xyz"));
String src = image.getAttribute("src");
return src.endsWith("image_true.png");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the "src" property and programmatically perform an HTTP GET. You can then assert the response code and the content type

Comment: I think you need to justify your comment.